# How to plot hairy inverse trigonometric functions?

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions, inverse-function

It is easy to plot functions like $y=\sin^{ -1}(x)$, $y=\cos^{-1}(x)$ and $y=\tan^{-1}(x)$. But how to proceed with the functions like $$y = \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)$$
And
$$y = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3x-x^3}{1-3x^2}\right)$$
Is there any general way to approach these problems?

Comment: Certainly: the *general* approach is the same as for any curve-sketching problem: find its domain, find where it's positive, where its first and second derivatives are positive, find asymptotes, etc. It's also possible to reason about the shape of these functions' graphs by decomposing them as compositions (in the obvious way) and thinking about the graphs of the inner and outer functions.

Answer (score 3):

**Curve I**

\begin{align*}
  x &= \tan t \\[5pt]
  \sin y &= \frac{2\tan t}{1+\tan^2 t} \\[5pt]
  &= \sin 2t \\[5pt]
  y &= n\pi+(-1)^{n}2t \\[5pt]
  y &=
  \left \{
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      -\pi-2\tan^{-1} x & , & x \le -1 \\
      2\tan^{-1} x & , & -1 < x < 1 \\
       \pi-2\tan^{-1} x & , & x \ge 1
\end{array}
  \right.
\end{align*}
[image]

**Curve II**
\begin{align*}
  x &= \tan t \\[5pt]
  \tan y &= \frac{3\tan t-\tan^3 t}{1-3\tan^2 t} \\[5pt]
  &= \tan 3t \\[5pt]
  y &= 3t+n\pi \\[5pt]
  y &=
  \left \{
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      3\tan^{-1} x+\pi & , & x \le -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\
      3\tan^{-1} x & , & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} < x < \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\
      3\tan^{-1} x-\pi & , & x \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}
\end{array}
  \right.
\end{align*}
[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you came up with those limits like when $x ≤ -1$ and how you got that $y=- \pi - 2tan^{-1}x$? I'm little confused in this part!

Comment: $$\binom{x}{y}=\binom{\tan t}{\sin^{-1} (\sin 2t)} \in (-\infty,\infty) \times \left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2} \right]$$ using **CAST** to verify for $t\in \left[-\frac{\pi}{2},-\frac{\pi}{2} \right]$, $\left[-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4} \right]$ and $\left[-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2} \right]$

$$\binom{x}{y}=\binom{\tan t}{\tan^{-1} (\tan 3t)} \in (-\infty,\infty) \times \left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2} \right]$$ using **CAST** to verify for $t\in \left[-\frac{\pi}{2},-\frac{\pi}{6} \right]$, $\left[-\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{6} \right]$ and $\left[-\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{2} \right]$